# Inline c# in XAML front-end: Why doesn't this work in XAML?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

Scenario:  Developing a "thick" client in UWP, using c# destined for the desktop of Windows 8.1/10 (a store app).

In my user interface, I tried to use the following inline

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock  x:Name="Qty_Size_Crust" Margin="25,10,20,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="25" Foreground="#ff230909" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" xml:space="preserve" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
if ({Binding WidgetName} == "Backend")
{             
        <Run Text="{Binding ItemCode, Converter=ItemCodeToDescriptionConverter}"/> 
}
else
{
       <Run Text="See Administrator}"/> 
}
    </TextBlock>
```

The compiler would accept this, but during execution, I would neither see Item Description nor See Administrator.  Is there something else I should be doing in order for this work?  I was able to work around this by putting the code in the ViewModel, but wondered why this didn't work (or maybe it shouldn't).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42980/How-to-embed-a-C-code-into-an-XAML-file

Comment: I wish, dude. That would be cool. I think you are in an ASP.Net mindset. C# can only exist in code-behind. Not in the declarative code. Sorry.

Comment: I swear I was able to do this in older flavors in XAML.  Perhaps my mind is going....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XAML doesn't work with inline scripts so the answer is simply - it's not supported.

In your example - the condition code is simply added as text runs in the TextBlock, so the compiler accepts that.

As for the best solution to your specific problem - a condition in the view model is a good one. A `TemplateSelector` would work on the view side, but requires more code. View model might actually also be the best place to put it if you want to be able to test it, so it really is the right way to do it. Putting logic in the view layer would simply add code that can't be unit-tested.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `TemplateSelector` is perhaps the worst-performing part of the XAML platform and isn't a good choice. I would recommend a visual state controlled by something in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks Filip, appreciate the insight!